# I can't send eth + data into a contract with etherjs

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, ethers.js

**> *Well, the problem is from my gas limit. I should increase the gas limit!***

I want to send eth + data into this contract: **0x5293Bb897db0B64FFd11E0194984E8c5F1f06178** like this transaction: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x64b9b55c3a1ddb68159156dee5dcf8cccaa42b9d9af9ae896df9ecd3a1922ac5

I can do it with myetherwallet:

[image]

But I got failed with etherjs, my code is below:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,waitTimeInMs));

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/my_api_key');
const eth_wei_minimal = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0');
const stream = fs.createReadStream('key_bridge_eth.csv');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: stream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

(async () => {
    var counter = 0;
    var done = 0;
    var errors = 0;

    for await (const line of rl) {
        const [privateKey, data] = line.split(",");
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey.trim(), provider);
        counter++;

        if (Number(await provider.getBalance(wallet.address)) > eth_wei_minimal) {
            try {
                const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet.address);
                console.log(wallet.address);
                const tx = {
                    to: "0x5293Bb897db0B64FFd11E0194984E8c5F1f06178",
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.2009900000009".toString()),
                    data: data.trim(),
                    chainID: '11155111',
                    nonce: nonce,
                    gasLimit: 116402,
                    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('1.7', 'gwei'),
                };
                console.log(data.trim());
                await sleep(1500);
                const recipt = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
                console.log(`tx claim = https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/${recipt.hash}`);

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`tx ERROR`);
                errors++;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(`Processed ${counter} keys, completed ${done} transactions, encountered ${errors} errors.`);
}) ();
```

And here is the data in file: `key_bridge_eth.csv`

> Privatekey, 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

And I get this error: `tx ERROR`

Please give me some advices. Thank you.